# Knife Angle constraint wrong cuts

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, knife-tool

I cut with Knife tool > angle constraint(relative) with 30 degrees increments and it works kind of weird. Should it work like that?! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vYADXDsQBJI0dZi1TonoY_x0G7jqcG4f/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @moonboots, what the difference betven "screen" and "relative" then. In orthographic i can do it with screen option.

Comment: Oops sorry I didn't read correctly

Comment: I'm not sure how the Relative option works actually

Comment: @moonboots, https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/113685